# Can't install R 3.6 in Raspberry pi 3 B in raspbian stretch

Tags: r, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, raspbian-stretch

### The problem

Hello everyone, I need to install R software (at least 3.5 but hopefully 3.6) in my raspberry pi 3 B

I started by doing the usual:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install r-base r-base-dev
```

Which works, but I get R 3.3

So then I tried what I found in this [webpage](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-debian-9/) and it works unil:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://cran.dcc.uchile.cl/bin/linux/debian stretch-cran35/'
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
(self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/stretch
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Please help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally after many tries I compiled it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gfortran libreadline6-dev libx11-dev libxt-dev \
       libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libcairo2-dev xvfb \
       libbz2-dev libzstd-dev liblzma-dev \
       libcurl4-openssl-dev \
       texinfo texlive texlive-fonts-extra \
       screen wget openjdk-8-jdk
cd /usr/local/src
sudo wget https://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.6.1.tar.gz
sudo su
tar zxvf R-3.6.1.tar.gz
cd R-3.6.1
./configure --enable-R-shlib #--with-blas --with-lapack #optional
make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf R-3.6.1*
exit
cd
```

If anyone has a faster better version all the better

Comment: Updating this for R 4.0.2 - obviously change the version numbers in the solution given by Derek. I also had to install PCRE2 from the sources. Do the following before running configure for R 4.0.2: `wget ftp://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre2-10.35.tar.gz; cd pcre2-10.35; ./configure; make; make install`